# Mobile app development: HTML5 Image or Canvas

Tags: html, css, mobile, html5-canvas

I'm fairly new to web development (but not programming) and needed some advice:

I am working on a mobile app using HTML5, CSS, and Javascript (and Cordova for device functionality).

The app will be similar to flashcards (those things you used to use as a kid to memorize things).  There will be some animation (flipping the card over), etc. but for the most part, the design of the flashcard will be static (borders with the main content in the center).

What would be the best way to proceed with that (drawing on a canvas or using an image for each flashcard?  I am interested in performance and visual considerations of the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the type of animation the cards will be doing, if they are flipping on the x/y axis you could simply have the image and manipulate its size/flip it etc with JS.

In my experience these kind of calculations/animations are quicker (if you want it to be compatible across multiple devices) however any more complicated animations should use the canvas - I have noticed when creating adverts for smartphones the canvas can really slow some animations down.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to prototype some things and see what happens.

Comment: No worries, as I said if you can do your animations with JavaScript then that should be faster on mobile browsers, anything you can't do with Javascript will probably have to use the Canvas which by all my testing is significantly slower :(